# Where will my full name be used?

Tags: 12.04, security, users, privacy

During installation, the installer told me my name would be used for things like the default 'from' in emails. So now I'm wondering:

- Where else will my name be used?
- What benefits do I get from using a real vs a fantasy name in my user's full name?
- Which programs can access that name? I'm worried about privacy/anonimity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "full name" is written along with your user name to `/etc/passwd` and available for any program on your system. You can change your full name at any time using the User dialog in the system settings.

It's used as a default by most programs that use something like a "full name". Other than the ones mentioned by you and Linux Distance that includes for example LibreOffice.

Answer (score 1):

I think the username used in the system is for user identification, while your "full name" Ubuntu requested is just used as an identity to display on the log in screen (useful in a company) and the Ubuntu's upper bar.